# How to debug a missing view

Tags: ember.js

From my router, I'm rendering a view:

```
App.MonthSummaryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        selectTab: function(name) {
            this.render(name, { into: 'month/summary', outlet: 'tab' });
        }
    }
});
```

As an example, name is `"summaryCompany"`. If I add a

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="summaryCompany">
    <h2>Test template</h2>
</script>
```

this template displays. But I tried to add a view to handle the events:

```
App.SummaryCompanyView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
      console.log('here');
    }
});
```

and I'm not getting anything. What am I missing?

Comment: you have a typo (a misplaced `'`) at the end of your view, is this maybe the problem?

Comment: no, that was just in SO. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide your entire code selection, or a JSBin / JSFiddle?

Possible approaches:

1. What's in your `month/summary` template / route / view?
2. Maybe you  can't call `render` from an event. What happens when instead of doing the render from inside `selectTab` you do it from the route's `renderTemplate` hook?
   `renderTemplate: function() { this.render("summaryCompanyView", { into: 'month/summary', outlet: 'tab' }); }`
3. You can try seeing if the view is inserted at all: in web inspector, find the ember-id of the div corresponding to view (somethign like `<div id="ember310" ...>`, then access the actual view object via  `Ember.Views.views.ember310` (or whatever id). You can check the view's class and see if it's `App.SummaryCompanyView` or a generic `Ember.View`
4. Lastly, what happens if you remove the inlined-template and specify the template on the View object via `templateName`?

Comment: I think #2 is what I need...how do you get the name of the class? I'm looking through the properties of the `Ember.View.views.ember310` object but am getting lost.

Comment: Now I'm really confused... I made a JSBin, and it worked. So I started adding back in parts from my main app, and it still works. I have no idea how to debug this!

Comment: `SummaryCompanyView` is simply not being picked up by ember. If I remove it, nothing changes; if I add `templateName` nothing changes. What could it possibly be?

Comment: Got it. I had copied the class to another file but forgot to change the name, so it was being overwritten. That was excruciating. Great tips, though, so thank you!

Comment: @SamSelikoff sometimes it's the obvious things! As for your question,  to get the class of the view, I just check ```Ember.View.views.ember310.constructor``` .. kinda hacky, but it works. I inspect the views so often during development that I usually end up writing a helper viewFromId function.